# Both resettable_device_id and device_id fields stopped being recorded in Firebase Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I use information from any of these fields to track unique device identificator. Usually about 10% of sessions per day were recorded with an empty field in both these fields. But for the last several days this number significantly increased. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

This is due to a bug that snuck into a recent version of Google Play Services. A fix is being rolled out at this moment, but unfortunately data for the affected devices will be lost in the meantime.

Comment: It looks like device_id is not available in Firebase Analytics BigQuery, what's the recommended way to identify a user's device? We're trying to use BigQuery data to create a list of members who installed the app before a certain date to give them access to premium features that will be added in the future.